# Cascading drop down in ReactJS controlled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I am trying to implement cascading drop down for in a controlled component.

Parent drop down:

```
<select id="Regions" className="validate" value={this.state.userRegionId} onChange={this.handleRegionChange}>
{this.handleGetRegions()}
</select>
```

The `handleGetRegions()` populates the parent drop down when the component is mounted using `componentDidMount`.

The `onChange` handler `handleRegionChange()` basically sets the `state` variable `userRegionId` based on the selected value.

```
handleRegionChange(event){
this.setState({userRegionId: event.target.value});
}
```

With the `state` value being updated, I use the `componentDidUpdate` to populate the child drop down. Reason I use `componentDidUpdate` is because `state` is updated asynchronously and the immediate value is only available here.

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  this.handleGetCountriesByRegion(this.state.userRegionId);
}
```

`handleGetCountriesByRegion` implementation:

```
handleGetCountriesByRegion(regionId){
  let regioncountryJSON = JSON.parse(locale["snclregioncountry-" + this.state.lang]);
  let countriesJSON = regioncountryJSON[regionId] != undefined ? regioncountryJSON[regionId].Countries : undefined;
  if (countriesJSON != undefined && countriesJSON.length > 0) {
    let countries = [];
    let defaultValue = locale["ddlCountry-" + this.state.lang];
    countries.push(<option selected disabled key={-1} value={defaultValue}>{defaultValue}</option>);
    countriesJSON.map((val) => {
      countries.push(<option key={val.id} value={val.id}>{val.name}</option>)
    });
    return countries;
  }
}
```

Finally I use `handleGetCountriesByRegion` as `options` for the child drop down like this:

```
<select id="Countries" value={this.state.userCountry} onChange={this.handleCountryChange}>
  {this.handleGetCountriesByRegion(this.state.userRegionId)}
</select>
```

It works fine but the problem is `handleGetCountriesByRegion` seems to be called twice. How can I make sure this function is only called once? Also, I want to know if this is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your componentDidUpdate() is called twice the reason being whenever your component is updated componentDidUpdate() is called and henceforth your function is called. The solution for this is to compare previous state with the new state like below:-

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(this.state.userRegionId != prevState.userRegionId) {
    this.handleGetCountriesByRegion(this.state.userRegionId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `handleGetCountriesByRegion` is beening called twice is because you use it both for each state update, and in the DOM:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  this.handleGetCountriesByRegion(this.state.userRegionId); <--- here
}
```

```
<select id="Countries" value={this.state.userCountry} onChange={this.handleCountryChange}>
  {this.handleGetCountriesByRegion(this.state.userRegionId)} <--- and here
</select>
```

Your structure is good, but consider refactoring `handleGetCountriesByRegion` to a component that receives an ID as a prop and changes its UI based on it.

Comment: I guessed the same. Do you have a sample or example of doing this?